# Open child fragment from NavigationDrawer Section

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer

i'm trying to open child fragment from an fragment of Navigation Drawer. Look at the picture below for understand me better please.

[image]

CODE:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ChatFragment(), MainActivity.CHAT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

ERROR DEBUG:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0b0072 (com.epiccode.enjoytheplace:id/fragment_container) for fragment ChatFragment{4211cf20 #1 id=0x7f0b0072 CHAT_FRAGMENT}
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:882)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NOTE: I'm using neokree [navigation drawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer)
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are placed that code inside Navigation Drawer fragment, and ofcourse it doesn't contain 'fragment_container' view inside it.

You have to call activity method, passing number or name of fragment which should be opened, e.g.:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).switchFragment(1);
```

Where switchFragment is something like:

```
public void switchFragment(int position) {
   switch (position) {
      case (1):
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN); 
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ChatFragment(), MainActivity.CHAT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
         fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); 
         fragmentTransaction.commit(); 
         break;
       .....
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but i get: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.epiccode.enjoytheplace.activity.NavigationBarActivity cannot be cast to com.epiccode.enjoytheplace.activity.MainActivity

Comment: Sorry, but what's about read your text of excepation? MainActivity was example, I didn't know in which Activity your Fragment. ((MainActivity) getActivity()) - change it to ((NavigationBarActivity) getActivity())